# How to convert byte to blob

Tags: java, servlets

I want to convert the byte into the blob type.

below is code but it gives error,

```
    Path path = Paths.get("filepath");
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    Blob blob=new Blob(data);
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

`--->` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html

Blob is an interface, to create an object you need implementation of Blob,
The only implementing class of Blob is `SerialBlob`

So, you would do,

`Blob b = new SerialBlob(data);`

`--->`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html